# R create ID within a group

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
df<-structure(list(IDFAM = c("2010 7599 2996 1", "2010 7599 3071 1", 
"2010 7599 3071 1", "2010 7599 3660 1", "2010 7599 4736 1", "2010 7599 6235 1", 
"2010 7599 6299 1", "2010 7599 9903 1", "2010 7599 11013 1", 
"2010 7599 11778 1", "2010 7599 11778 1", "2010 7599 12248 1", 
"2010 7599 13127 1", "2010 7599 14261 1", "2010 7599 16280 1", 
"2010 7599 16280 1", "2010 7599 16280 1", "2010 7599 16280 1", 
"2010 7599 16280 1", "2010 7599 17382 1"), AGED = c(45L, 47L, 
24L, 46L, 46L, 44L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 16L, 43L, 46L, 44L, 47L, 43L, 
16L, 20L, 18L, 18L, 43L)), .Names = c("IDFAM", "AGED"), row.names = c("5614", 
"5748", "5753", "6864", "8894", "11761", "11884", "18738", "20896", 
"22351", "22353", "23267", "24939", "27072", "30946", "30947", 
"30949", "30950", "30952", "33034"), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to assign an ID to each observation having the same `IDFAM` value ranging from 1 to n, where n is the number of observations with the same value of `IDFAM`. This would result in the following table:

```
IDFAM              AGED     ID
2010 7599 2996 1    45       1
2010 7599 3071 1    47       1
2010 7599 3071 1    24       2
2010 7599 3660 1    46       1
2010 7599 4736 1    46       1
2010 7599 6235 1    44       1
2010 7599 6299 1    43       1
2010 7599 9903 1    43       1
2010 7599 11013 1   43       1
2010 7599 11778 1   16       1
2010 7599 11778 1   43       2
2010 7599 12248 1   46       1
2010 7599 13127 1   44       1
2010 7599 14261 1   47       1
2010 7599 16280 1   43       1
2010 7599 16280 1   16       2
2010 7599 16280 1   20       3
2010 7599 16280 1   18       4
2010 7599 16280 1   18       5
2010 7599 17382 1   43       1
```

How can I do this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are several ways.

In base R, use `ave`:

```
with(df, ave(rep(1, nrow(df)), IDFAM, FUN = seq_along))
#  [1] 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 1
```

---

With the "data.table" package, use `sequence(.N)`:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[, ID := sequence(.N), by = IDFAM]
```

---

With the "dplyr" package, try:

```
df %>% group_by(IDFAM) %>% mutate(count = sequence(n()))
```

or (as recommended by Hadley in the comments):

```
df %>% group_by(IDFAM) %>% mutate(count = row_number(IDFAM))
```

---

#### Update

Since this seems to be something that is asked for relatively frequently, this feature has been added as a function (`getanID`) in my "splitstackshape" package. It is based on the "data.table" approach above.

```
library(splitstackshape)
getanID(df, id.vars = "IDFAM")
#                 IDFAM AGED .id
#  1:  2010 7599 2996 1   45   1
#  2:  2010 7599 3071 1   47   1
#  3:  2010 7599 3071 1   24   2
#  4:  2010 7599 3660 1   46   1
#  5:  2010 7599 4736 1   46   1
#  6:  2010 7599 6235 1   44   1
#  7:  2010 7599 6299 1   43   1
#  8:  2010 7599 9903 1   43   1
#  9: 2010 7599 11013 1   43   1
# 10: 2010 7599 11778 1   16   1
# 11: 2010 7599 11778 1   43   2
# 12: 2010 7599 12248 1   46   1
# 13: 2010 7599 13127 1   44   1
# 14: 2010 7599 14261 1   47   1
# 15: 2010 7599 16280 1   43   1
# 16: 2010 7599 16280 1   16   2
# 17: 2010 7599 16280 1   20   3
# 18: 2010 7599 16280 1   18   4
# 19: 2010 7599 16280 1   18   5
# 20: 2010 7599 17382 1   43   1
```

Comment: Thanks, I particularly like the `with`/`ave` method. Simple and efficient.

Comment: Better to use `row_number()` in dplyr.

Comment: @AnandaMahto. I must say. All this is very nice!

Comment: @hadley, not sure if I used `row_number()` correctly in my edit here. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, that's right. In dplyr 0.2, you'll be able to use it bare, `count = row_number()`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using sequence, but using `row_number()` will also work with SQL backends, and knowing the common [window functions](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html) allows you to solve a wide class of problems.

Comment: What's the difference between using seq_len(.N) or sequence(.N) ?

Answer (score 4):

With dplyr 0.5 you can use the `group_indices` function. Although it do not support `mutate`, the following approach is straightforward:

```
df$id <- df %>% group_indices(IDFAM)
```